# Charges on conductors

Tags: electrostatics, charge, gauss-law, conductors

Suppose two similar conductors which are unequally charged are brought close to each other,then charges from one will flow to another and ultimately both of them will be equally charged and either both will be positive or both will be negative.Now the conductors are separated.Suppose I draw a Gaussian surface as shown in the figure
As the electric field inside a conductor is always zero flux through this surface will be zero.
The electric field between the conductors will always be perpendicular to the Area vector of the Gaussian surface and hence flux through the entire surface will also be zero which implies that the total charge inside it will be zero.
That implies that the conductors cannot have charge of the same sign.As both the statements contradict each other.Which of them is correct[image][image]

Comment: I think you should take the effort to write your question more clearly, and to type again the relevant parts from the images. Anyways, to give a hint on your question, ask yourself: "if the two spheres do not have exactly the same charge after they have been put in contact, then which of the two has the larger value of charge?". The spheres are identical, so they _must_ have the same charge, after being put in contact.

Comment: I agree they should have the same charge but I think it should be opposite in sign.Please see the gauss law

Comment: If they have opposite charges, but they're touching, what prevents the charges flowing toward each other and compensating each other?

Comment: But then this does not satisfy the gauss law.Someone explain

Comment: Where in your example says the author that the two plates are put in contact? The situation you are asking is completely different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem deals with two different situation.  In the first the two conductors momentarily touch. If the charges are unequal but opposite, the larger one will neutralize the other. What remains will be divided equally. These two parts will repel each other and move to opposite sides of the plates. Then there is no charge within your Gaussian surface, and no flux. In the second, the two charges on the inner surfaces are equal and opposite: still no net charge or flux.

Answer (score -1):

The net charge inside the gaussian surface you have drawn (v3 of the post) is zero. Let's see:

1. First the plates are separated and each one has its own net charge.
2. Once we put them in contact you can think of it as turning two plates into one thick plate. If initially they had opposite but unequal charges, the one with more charge in absolute value will neutralize the other and the rest will be distributed through the surface of this new plate in such a way that the electric field vanishes inside. In particular, if you ignore border effects, it's easy to see that you would have half the charge on the top surface (at the top of the plate labeled A in your figure) and half on the bottom surface (at the bottom of B). The electric field inside would be zero.
3. Now, when you separate them again charges will not move, because the only thing you are doing is breaking the big plate into two plates and creating a volume of air in between, but you are not creating electric field inside the plates, so the charges don't need to move. If the charges remain both at the top of A and at the bottom of B then the electric field is still zero inside the plates in this new situation (as well as in the region betweem them).

Therefore the electric field is zero at all the points in your gaussian surface. And there is no net charge at the bottom surface of A or at the top surface of B.

---

EDIT: Here you can see two snapshots of an online electrostatics simulator, which you can find and use yourself at [Falstad Electrostatics Simulation](https://www.falstad.com/emstatic/index.html). The first figure shows a typical parallel plate capacitor, where the plates are subject to a potential difference, hence they have charges of opposite signs. In this simulator, electric field goes from white (stronger) to green (weaker). You can see it is stronger between the plates. The charge inside the plates is also drawn. Yellow points represent positive charge and blue points negative charge. You can see different shades of yellow and blue. Lighter shades mean less charge, while darker shades mean more charge. You can find all the directions on how to interpret the results of the simulator at [Electrostatics Applet Directions](https://www.falstad.com/emstatic/directions.html). Notice that the surfaces with more charge concentration are the inner walls of the plates.

[image: Electric field and charge in a parallel plate capacitor. Simulated using Falstad.]

In this second figure you can see two parallel plates having the same amount of charge and the same potential (this is what would happen once you put them in contact and then separate them). I have labelled them A and B as in your question. I have also drawn the gaussian surface. Notice that there is no charge inside the surface. That doesn't mean there is no charge in the plates! The charge is now mostly in the outer surfaces of the plates (top of A and bottom of B). So there is no contradiction, there is no charge inside the gaussian surface and also the electric field is zero at the points on the surface. The reason for this is just what I explained before.

[image: Electric field and charge distribution in a parallel plate capacitor with same potential between the two plates.]

Comment: I dont understand you are claiming that net flux is zero but charge is still there?

Comment: Can you explain how the charge will be zero inside in this case

Comment: Your answer is extremely confusing

Comment: Kindly provide  a diagram or maths ro it

Comment: Naruto and @BlackSusanoo, I have edited the answer hoping it helps getting some insight on what is happening

Comment: @Urb I believe thie diagram from the question is from the Book HC Verma and charges on the surfaces are on the lenght side of cuboid conductor. You have drawn the charges on the width sides whilst the charges are present on the front and back of the cuboid

Comment: Yes @BlackSusanoo is correct I have provided an image of the solution in which he has shown the distribution of charges in this case in an edit

Comment: First of all, I haven't drawn the charge, the simulator has. And second, is the charge around the corners you are worried about? Because that is just because charge tends to accumulate at the surfaces that have more curvature.